# PHP Riak in place update

Tags: php, riak

From what I can see, when using Riak to update an object, I first need to load the object into PHP, then edit the object, then store the object back to the Riak database.

I was wondering if there is a way to update a bucket without pulling it into PHP first. That way, it would save on the network I/O and latency of pulling it into the PHP script.

Can objects be edited directly on the Riak side of things?

Edit:

Is there away to push data to the end of a raik object, so if i have an object that is numeric array can i make a push to add subject that i know its not there or no in place updates what so ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Riak has no ability to modify an object in place. The method you describe (read/modify/write) is how you modify an object in Riak.

Comment: Is there away to push data to the end of a raik object, so if i have an object that is numeric array can i make a push to add subject that i know its not there or no in place updates what so ever

Comment: No. You can not modify an object in place in any way. You have to read it, modify it, then write it back.